# QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "y"

Tags: qt, qml, model-binding, loader, qqmlcomponent

How can i over come this issue:

QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "y"

```
Loader {
id: grooveLoader
property QtObject styleData: QtObject {
readonly property int handlePosition: handleLoader.x + handleLoader.width/2
}
x: padding.left
sourceComponent: groove
width: (horizontal ? parent.width : parent.height) - padding.left - padding.right
y: Math.round(padding.top + (Math.round(horizontal ? parent.height : parent.width - padding.top - padding.bottom) - grooveLoader.item.height)/2)
}
```

QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "x"

```
Loader {
id: handleLoader
sourceComponent: handle
anchors.verticalCenter: grooveLoader.verticalCenter
x: Math.round((control.__handlePos - control.minimumValue) / (control.maximumValue - control.minimumValue) * ((horizontal ? root.width : root.height) - item.width))
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't use anchors and absolute positioning together.

Comment: Oh i see but how can use them differently for same var?

Comment: you must first explain what you want to achieve

Comment: The path of this file is :C:\Qt\5.12.8\msvc2017_64\qml\QtQuick\Controls\Styles\Base\SliderStyle.qml, i am not using this in other place also, it gives above error.